# ASP.NET MVC and Persian friendly URLs

Tags: url, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, persian

I'm developing an application with ASP.NET MVC 4 and I wanna my URLs look like below :

```
http://www.mysite.com/Product/Category/2/دربهای-چوبی
```

to do that I'm using this kind of URL pattern in `Global.asax` :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name:"ViewProduct",
                url:"Product/Category/{Id}/{productName}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Category", id = UrlParameter.Optional, productName = "" }
            );
```

and in my view I'm using generating my URLs with this way :

```
<a href="/Product/Category/@item.Id/@Url.ToFriendlyUrl(item.Name)">@item.Name</a>
```

as you can see I'm create extension method called `ToFriendlyUrl` :

```
public static string ToFriendlyUrl(this UrlHelper helper,
            string urlToEncode)
        {
            urlToEncode = (urlToEncode ?? "").Trim().ToLower();

            StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char ch in urlToEncode)
            {
                switch (ch)
                {
                    case ' ':
                        url.Append('-');
                        break;
                    case '&':
                        url.Append("and");
                        break;
                    case '\'':
                        break;
                    default:
                        if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') ||
                            (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'))
                        {
                            url.Append(ch);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            url.Append('-');
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return url.ToString();
        }
```

above way works correctly for English URLs(productName's segment) :

```
http://www.mysite.com/Product/Category/3/category-type-one
```

but for Persian URLs I'm getting this URL for example :

```
http://www.mysite.com/Product/Category/1/--------------
```

for example second one should have be:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Product/Category/2/دربهای-چوبی
```

How can I change the code to work with Persian URLs?

**PS** : I know in Persian language we don't have lower and upper cases and I omitted this line of code :

```
urlToEncode = (urlToEncode ?? "").Trim().ToLower();
```

But still I've same problem.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This if

```
                if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') ||
                    (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'))
```

means only English numbers and characters are allowed. But Persian characters have a different range:

```
 public static bool ContainsFarsi(string txt)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt) &&
                    Regex.IsMatch(txt, @"[\u0600-\u06FF]");
        }
```

+
Don't use that `ToFriendlyUrl` method. Create an extension method to apply your filtering and then use the standard `Html.ActionLink` method and pass your parameters as `new route values` or it's better to use the T4MVC HTML helper methods.
By constructing your links manulally, you will lose a lot of features like adjusting the root path based on the current domain or sub domain and also encoding the special characters and many outer built-in features.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Is there any example to do that (constructing links manulally)? for example in your website How do you handle these type of URLs?

Comment: It's the standard Html.ActionLink method + an extension method to normalize the Persian characters. you can find `ToSeoUrl` method here: http://www.dotnettips.info/post/894

Comment: thanks, I'm using your method but I've a problem when using Action method like this : `@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, actionName:"Category", controllerName: "Product", routeValues: new {Id=item.Id, productName=item.Name.ToSeoUrl() }, htmlAttributes:null)` my URL will be : `/Product/Category/2?productName=دربهای-چوبی` how can I have `/Product/Category/2/دربهای-چوبی` ?

Comment: Your new `ViewProduct` route should be defined before the `DefaultRoute`.